# How do I use the value of a variable in a symbol name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
  case value
  when 1
    increment!(:service_1, 1)
```

How do I insert *value* variable in :service_**1** instead **1**? I need a dynamic value here.

```
increment!(:service_value, 1) #doesn't work
```

Comment: `increment!("service_#{value}".to_sym, value)`?

Comment: `increment!(:service_value, value)` - second value increments first value and it must be static, I need `:service_#{my_variable_is_here}` - but it doesn't work too, because "#" is opening comment

Comment: Why didn't try the first comment exactly as it is given ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby lets you use string interpolation with symbols:

```
value = 1
increment!(:"service_#{value}", value)
```